# When is a constructor called "default constructor"?

Tags: c++, terminology, default-constructor

If we say that the `default constructor` is that constructor without parameters, can we also say the the constructor created by the compiler is also a `default constructor`?

Comment: Your question is just a play on a technicality, maybe it should say "default constructor" and "default compiler constructor". I'll agree it can be ambiguous, but it can generally be assumed from the context.

Answer (score 20):

A default constructor is one that *can be called* without arguments.

C++98 **§12.1/5**:

> A *default* constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of `X` that can be called without an argument. If there is no *user-declared* constructor for class `X`, a default constructor is implicitly declared.

Comment: "> implicitly declared" \n This is NOT always true. One example is for class WontGenerateDefCtoByCompiler below. :-)

Comment: added 4 other conditions in which compiler generate implicit default ctor. please see below for edited response of mine.

Comment: @Viren: it's a quote from the standard. since the standard *defines* the language you can't argue with the standard, except by claiming a defect in the standard (in which case you should submit a Defect Report). however, i think you're just misinterpreting the word "declared". cheers,

Answer (score 8):

The default constructor is a constructor that may be *called* without arguments.  So this is either a constructor that has no arguments, or a constructor whose arguments all have default values.

But yes, the compiler generates a default constructor if you don't provide any other constructors.

Recommended reading: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.4.

Answer (score 3):

```
                         +------> Implicitly GENERATED by compiler
                         |
                         |
Default Constructor -----+
                         |
                         |
                         +------> Explicitly provided by programmer
```

Basically, a default ctor is a ctor with no-args.

PLEASE note that the compiler will not generate any default ctor in following case:

```
    class WontGenerateDefCtoByCompiler
    {
private:
    char* iHaHaPtr;
    };
```

Reason being the compiler does not see any need to initialize programmer provided pointer. It is programmer's responsbility to correctly write and init the default ctor.

If you, on other hand, write a virtual function inside the above class, compiler will definitely generate a default ctor (but won't initialise iHahaptr pointer for you). Further, such ctor will be generated ONLY IF an instance of that object was created in the program (otherwise, again, no ctor will be generated by compiler).

These are the ONLY 4 conditions in which compiler will IMPLICITLY generate default ctor (if not provided by programmer):

```
(1) The class has a virtual function (Why? need to setup vptr correctly )
(2) The class is derived from another class that has default ctor (either implicitly generated or explictly provided)
(3) The class has a member that has default ctor (either implicitly generated or explictly provided)
(4) The class is virtually derived from other class
```

In all other cases, compiler will not generate any default ctor.

Comment: Is it defined by the standard or implementation-defined? I'm asking because I've just tested it and G++ generates an empty default constructor if there is a subclass with a user-defined default constructor. It does literally nothing, but it's there in the assembly output. If I remove the user-defined constructor from the subclass, the compiler generates no constructors at all.

Comment: It is "implied" by the Standard but the Standard does not explicitly state that. I don't have a copy of standard with me on my iPhone, but I remeber their is some adverbs used by standard that implies the above.

Comment: @Viren: a Default Constructor is a constructor is a constructor that can be called without providing any argument. A constructor that has been declared as taking some arguments but provide a default for each of them is a Default Constructor for the class.

Comment: @Matthieu: yes I agree but I didn't understand how it is related to my above answer. Did I say something wrong? Please correct me if I said something wrong.

Comment: @Viren: I think that the statement "Basically, a default ctor is a ctor with no-args." could be misinterpreted. I would a "that can be invoked" before the "with".

Comment: I disagree. I think that the compiler will generate a default ctor - it just is empty.

Comment: I think you are confusing _implicit declaration_ of a default constructor and _implicit definition_ of a default constructor. An default constructor is _always_ implicitly declared for any class that has no user-declared constructors. It is only implicitly defined when it is used; whether a constructor is used to initialize a class instance depends on how it is initialized and whether it is a POD-type. It's not quite the same as your 4 conditions which are more like the conditions for a constructor being non-trivial.

Comment: @Charles: Could you please elaborate more on your statement: "It is only implicitly defined when it is used". As I understand, it will be implicitly defined when it is used _and_ _iff_ the above 4 conditions satisfy, i.e. to say that it is a case of non-triviality. So I'm sorry I did not understand your sentence. And also sorry for replying so late. I didn't see it before somehow.

Comment: This answer is basically completely wrong. A default constructor can have parameters (as long as they have default arguments). A default constructor is _always_ implicitly-declared if there is no user-declared constructor, also in the example provided in the answer. It will be implicitly-defined when odr-used, even if it is trivial (for example if declaring `WontGenerateDefCtoByCompiler var;`). The conditions at the end seem to be to be made up on the spot and do not correlate with anything that the standard says about default constructors.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just say that "the constructor created by the compiler is also a default constructor". If there are no constructors declared, the compiler generates a default constructor *and* a copy constructor (and possibly a move constructor if we are talking C++0x here). When you mention just "the constructor created by the compiler", you are actually talking about at least two constructors at once. So you can only say that "the *default* constructor created by the compiler is also a default constructor", but this sounds like something Capt. Obvious would say.

Comment: @Sergey: and you can add the implicitly defined Move Constructor (though there are some restrictions to its generation) as one more constructor that the compiler may define :)

Comment: @Matthieu, aren't move constructors c++0x-specific? The question isn't tagged c++0x. Or do C++ compilers generate them too, as a sort of optimization? I can't imagine how they would work, though.

Comment: @Sergey: they are C++0x specific, but C++0x is a specialization of C++ as I see it :) They simply work by invoking the move constructor of each and every item, in a very similar manner as the copy constructor. There are restrictions though, as to when a compiler will be authorized to generate them, and I am not sure it's finalized yet as to which conditions it'll be.

Comment: @Matthieu, well then C++ is a specialization of C, but one probably wouldn't mention constructors when talking about C. So I still think move constructors have nothing to do with this question. It's arguable, though.

Comment: @Sergey: I would not compare C++ with C (despite the name) because of the incompatibilities and widely different programming styles. On the other hand most people, when they state C++, do not bother, or do not even know, which version of the standard (C++98, C++03 or C++0x) they are asking for.

Comment: @Matthieu, well, even different C++ standards have some incompatibilities. So I guess you could consider C++0x just another C++ standard. I think I'll add a note about C++0x after all.