# How to set a default constructor when there's more than one

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I'm learning about constructors in C++ and I understand that you can declare more than one constructor.  You can see below that I have 2 `Date` constructors below, but I want to set `Date(long)` as the default one.  Can someone please explain how I would do this?

Ok so apparently the question above makes so sense.  I am working a problem from the book and this is what it says:

> Modify Program 10.3 so that the only data member of the class is a long integer named yyyymmdd. Do this by substituting the declaration long yyyymmdd; for these existing declarations:
>
> int month;
>     int day;
>     int year;
>
> Using the same constructor prototypes currently declared in the class declaration section, rewrite them so that the Date(long) method becomes the default constructor, and the Date(int, int, int) method converts a month, day, and year into the correct form for the class data members.

Program 10.3:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Date
{
    private:
        int month, day, year;
    public:
        Date(int=7, int=4, int=2012);
        Date(long);
        void showDate();
};

Date::Date(int mm, int dd, int yyyy)
{
   month = mm;
   day = dd;
   year = yyyy;
}

Date::Date(long yyyymmdd)
{
    year = int(yyyymmdd/10000);
    month = int( (yyyymmdd - year*10000)/100);
    day = int(yyyymmdd - year*10000 - month*100);
}

void Date::showDate()
{
    cout << "The date is "
         << setfill('0')
         << setw(2) << month << '/'
         << setw(2) << day << '/'
         << setw(2) << year % 100;
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Date a;
    Date b(4,1,1998);
    Date c = Date(20090515L);

    a.showDate();
    b.showDate();
    c.showDate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is default constructor?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The compiler chooses which constructor to  call based on what arguments you supply. What would specifying a "default constructor" do?

Comment: There can be at-most-one constructor that takes no *required* parameters, including in that pool constructors that take *all* optional parameters. What your asking, quite literally, make no sense. You choose which is the "default" by fulfilling that requirement *once*.

Comment: A default constructor is a constructor without parameters. See this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4836611/651848

Comment: @rkyser There is a difference between a constructor without parameters and a constructor that requires *no arguments*. The latter doesn't imply the former, though the former certainly complies with the latter.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill ok i posted the question from the C++ book i'm reading.... maybe I am misunderstanding?

Comment: @WhozCraig Ok i posted the question from the textbook I'm working... does it make sense now?

Answer (score 3):

The default values for the month/day/year constructor you have make it the default constructor (you can call it with no parameters. What you want to do is un-default those and default the parameter to the `long` constructor:

```
    Date(int, int, int);
    Date(long = 20120704);
```

Comment: Thanks Mark.  This time I actually stated the direct question from the book I'm working.  Does this change your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set a default constructor. Per definition, the default constructor is the constructor that can be invoked without arguments.

It is automatically used if you do not (or cannot) specify arguments when creating an object.

For example if you define an array of objects, all of those objects will be constructed *using the default constructor*:

```
Date dates[5]; // Will create 5 Dates using Date::Date(7, 4, 2012)
```

Comment: Thanks @king_nak.  This time I actually stated the direct question from the book I'm working.  Does this change your answer?

Comment: Well, then Mark B's answer is correct. the constructor has to be callable without arguments. This means the `long`-c'tor must have default parameters. *Note*: Callable without arguments doesn't necessarily mean that it cannot have arguments; it just needs default parameters for all of them!